# Is the posted value for a form input, where type=hidden, a string?

Tags: php, hidden-field

I am trying to streamline my php for my current website. Typically, I have treated (successfully) submitted form values using the == operator, as follows;

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['yes_or_no'])) {
    if (($_POST['hidden']) == 'yes') {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Yep');
        </script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script>
        alert('Nope');
        </script>";
    }
}
else//etc.
?>

<html><head></head><body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" id="YesNoForm">
<button name="yes_or_no" type="submit">Click</button>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="yes">
</form>

</body></html>
```

However, should I be treating the hidden **value** of the form (the value equals "yes" in the form above) as having the same type and value using the === operator (and therefore use === 'yes' in the code above)? Is the hidden value a text string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you wouldn't is if you were debating between numbers as strings (currency, for example) or BOOLEAN phrases ("true" vs TRUE).

"yes" is always going to be a string so yes, please use `===`

Comment: Thanks for your help...to followup, if the hidden value was 10, would this be by default an integer or string? I interpret it to be an integer...correct?

Comment: Depends how you assign it.  If you say `$var = "10";` then it's a string but if you say `$var = 10;` then it's an integer

Comment: You could even say `$var = "10"; $var += 10;` and PHP would turn it into an integer automatically

Comment: OK...I understand all of this to mean if the hidden value="10", then $_POST['hidden'] is a number (equals 10) not a string.

Comment: If you would like to force it one way or another you can do that as well - `if( (int)$_POST['hidden'] === 10 ) { take over the world }`  -  Here's a live example for you: http://codepad.org/OUu7LM1P

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't require explicit variable type definition. so if you assign it a string it will consider it as string if you assign an integer it will be considered as integer value and so on.
So yes the value here will be string. For better understanding you can refer

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php. Hope that's helpful :)